# How can i find out which DLL files on Windows are used for offline validation of windows activation keys?

Tags: windows, windows-activation, dll, product-key

I am planning to build a tool that is similar to the [Microsoft PID checker](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_pid_checker.html) but with some new features. Microsoft PID checker can check the activation keys for a variety of Microsoft products such as Windows 7,8 and 10 but also Microsoft Server products such as MS Office and Visual Studio. Apparently it can do all this just by calling certain DLL files according [to this post on mydigitallife.net](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/are-pid-checkers-realiable-it-says-all-keys-are-valid.82121/#post-1610270). The post mentions `pidgenx.dll` but there could be more dll's involved.

My question is: How can i find out which DLL files are used by windows to perform certain functions, such as validating product keys? Does the microsoft website have a reference section somewhere that describes every DLL file that Windows uses? All i could find was [this DLL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-reference) but it doesn't say anything about which DLL files there are and what they do.

Comment: You could use "Dependency Walker" https://dependencywalker.com/ to trace those dlls and functions.

Comment: @martinist I was already aware of the dependency walker tool. In fact [there are multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437432/is-there-a-way-to-find-all-the-functions-exposed-by-a-dll) to get a list of callable functions for a DLL. But i was wondering if there exists documentation online that explains the workings of all the DLLs in detail. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Also `dependency walker` apparently [doesn't work with windows 10+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/592824/process-explorer-and-dependency-walker).